# CertPathValidatorException when accesing WebService from Tomcat WebApp

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, certificate, httpclient

First: I know, there are a lot of "CertPathValidatorException" threads and i checked them already :)

I have the following problem, for which i just can't find a solution. I would realy appreciate some help.

We have an tomcat6 on which an java web application is running. The ssl configuration seems to be ok. Checking with f.e. sslshopper shows no problems. You can connect via browser and https without anyproblem. So, the way in looks good.

From a class of the web application we calling an https webservice with apache HTTPClient (Simple SOAP POST). When we do so, an exception is thrown:

```
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: CA key usage check failed: keyCertSign bit is not set
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1697)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:258)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:252)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1165)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:610)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:546)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:945)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1190)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:657)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:108)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:502)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
        at net.umbrella.services.webclient.myclimate.MyClimateWebservice.callWebService(MyClimateWebservice.java:151)
        ... 67 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: CA key usage check failed: keyCertSign bit is not set
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:266)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:249)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:162)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:235)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:147)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1144)
        ... 85 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: CA key usage check failed: keyCertSign bit is not set
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:153)
```

The strange thing is: If we run our unit tests on the system - which also contain the problematic HTTPClient call - everything is ok. For me, that looks like a problem with the tomcat configuration. If i check the provider of the web service with sslshopper, his certificates look good, too.

I'm realy not an expert on the topic and most of the configuration was done by our hoster which can't find the problem either (The problem appeared suddenly some weeks ago).

A general question: Which keystore is used for an HTTPClient call from the web application? The systems keystore or a specific one which has to be provided by tomcat? Is the tomcat ssl configuration connected to an https request from the webapplication anyway?

Thanks!

Best regards,

Robert

**SOLVED: We finally solved the problem. The base jvm for the system was SUN JDK but for the tomcat OpenJDK was defined as JVM. Switching back to SUN JDK solved all our problems.**

Answer (score 0):

Answering the Tomcat aspects of this question:

If you make an HTTPS connection from a web application, Tomcat has zero involvement in the process. You'll need to configure HttpClient using whatever API HttpClient provides.

Regarding the error message you are seeing, it looks like your trust store isn't quite right. Might you be missing an intermediate certificate?

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure about that and somehow i was not able to find an answer to this question  with google. So at least i can stop looking for a problem in the tomcat configuration. Still, it's strange that the problem only appears in the tomcat container and not in the unit tests.